# Are there any solutions available that would eliminate the need to add `jvm` options when using Java 9 modules?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I am new to using `Java 9` modules.

I am aware that there are different types of `Java 9` modules such as `Automatic modules` and `Unnamed modules`.

I am curious why I am able to use third-party dependencies such as `google-guava` as `Automatic modules` directly in a module, but when I use a library that I have written which does not have a `module-info.java` file, I need to add `jvm` options like `--upgrade-module-path`. Are there any solutions available that would eliminate the need to add `jvm` options?

Here is a link to my demo: https://github.com/FadeDemo/java-module-demo/blob/main/module-consumer-new/src/main/java/org/fade/demo/module/consumer/niu/Test.java

Comment: Do you understand the *actual purpose* of the `--upgrade-module-path` option?

Comment: @Holger It is used to specify the location of updated or upgraded modules when running a modular Java application. I tried to use `--module-path`, but I need to specify all the modules, which I haven't encountered when I didn't use unnamed modules. Perhaps, I may have some confusion regarding the usage of modules. Could you please suggest some better advice on how to use them effectively?

Comment: You can specify directories *containing* the modules in `--module-path`, rather than each module. But, of course, it requires a suitable directory structure to be an advantage. There is no way to use modules without specifying the path to the modules. Apparently, you’re running in an environment which generates the startup options for you, so the fact that your module’s path is missing, is a configuration problem of that environment. The purpose of `--upgrade-module-path` is to specify a path to upgraded versions *of the JDK modules*. It’s not for fixing problems with the ordinary module path.